# How can I use reactjs state for component class?

Tags: reactjs, class, components, state

I have a sidebar component and the css prepared (`.sidebar.active` is the class whenever the sidebar is shown) in React:

```
export default function Sidebar() {
   return (
     <div className="sidebar">This is a sidebar</div>
   )
}
```

I want to save the state where the sidebar is toggled/active in React and since this is not a class I will have to use the `useState` hook, right? So it might look something like this:

```
export default function Sidebar() {
   const [toggled, setToggled] = useState();

   return (
     <div className="sidebar">This is a sidebar</div>
   )
}
```

How can I dynamically add/remove the `.active` class? I was thinking of adding additional string, like:

```
<div className="sidebar {toggled}">This is a sidebar</div>
```

so `toggled` is either an empty string or `active`. What is the correct way? Is there a way where I can dynamically add/remove the class from the `classList` of the DOM element? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `className={toggled ? "sidebar active" : "sidebar"}`, or similar code

Comment: I was thinking of this too Nicholas, thank you for the hint. Is there a way to modify the classList directly?

Comment: `Is there a way to modify the classList directly?` What do you mean by "directly"? If you mean using code like `document.getElementById` to find the element on the page, and then use plain javascript to change it, you should not do that in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to toggle the classlist.

```
export default function Sidebar() {
const [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

return (
 <div className={toggled ? "sidebar active" : "sidebar"}>This is a sidebar</div>
)}
```